# Built-in function name as identifier name

Tags: python, python-3.x

When we assign to a name that refers a built-in function, it did not complain. However, when we try to use it within the same built-in function `chr(chr)`, we get the issue cause of class in symbols...
Question is, whether this holds as a bug in the python interpreter ??

```
for chr in range[69,91]:
    print(chr)      # no Error
```

But when

```
print(chr(chr))   # Throws an error.
```

Comment: what error is it?

Comment: chr is now referring to the value yielded by the range, and has no longer any thing to do with the built-in function. What you wrote is equivalent to `foo = 69; print(foo(foo))` which makes no sense because an int is not callable

Comment: A possible source of confusion (depending on OP's background) is that, somewhat surprisingly, in R you *can* do something like `sin = pi/4` and then evaluate `sin(sin)` to get `0.7071068` -- but it is R rather than Python which is unusual here.

Comment: `range[69,91]` is not valid. You probably meant `range(69,91)`, unless you reassigned `range` as something else as well ;)

Comment: @njzk2 I assume the error is `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: Its certainly not a bug. Builtins is just a namespace and it can be overwritten or masked with a higher priority namespace. Python would have to special case this one namespace to "fix" the problem. Imagine if every creation of a variable had to be checked against builtins.... never mind that somebody might want to mask a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing scopes and namespaces.

If you hadn't assigned *any* value to `chr`, then an attempt to reference its value would result in finding the name in the built-in *scope*, where it refers to a built-in function.

After the assignment performed by the `for` loop, you assigning a value to `chr` in the *current* scope, so the lookup for `chr` succeeds in that scope, without referring to the built-in scope.

When you write `chr(chr)`, *both* references are looked up in the current scope, where the name `chr` is found to refer to an instance of `int`. There aren't two *namespaces*, where the first use (which looks like a function call) is distinct from the second use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
toChar = chr
for chr in range(69,91):
    print(toChar(chr))
```

Comment: a lot better to rename the loop var than to rename the build-in

Comment: @rioV8 yes in this situation you are right but maybe we have to use a name that it is a built-in function

Comment: that is confusing for the developers, just use a different name, or just append `_` but that is also confusing

Comment: @rioV8 if we download a source code that use a name like built-in function what can we do? change it? or use a tricky? (i know that we shouldn't use name like  built-in functions name but because  built-in functions name have general name that every programmer use them in normal programs maybe we use them unwanted)

Comment: don't use it, it will force you to write bad code if you need to modify it